# Can I upload database backup made through cPanel into phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel, mybb

I have been using mybb forum software. As, I use shared hosting so they had provided me cPanel. Through it I had make a backup which is a .gzip file.

Now, my query here is that I want to upload it to another server to do some experiments with my forum. Can I upload the file through phpmyadmin? As my server has no cPanel installed. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

I've previously installed a backup of MyBB through phpmyadmin using this method. Just create a fresh install of MyBB on another server, after installation head to phpmyadmin, go to the database you installed MyBB in, click the import tab, select your gzip file, upload the file, and everything should be restored correctly. (Side note: You may have to configure settings.php (changes in file path or cookie path) within the /inc/ folder and/or rebuild your mybb cache from the forum admincp)